# Scroll bottom to a page with infinite loading and click links present on page while scrolling up

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am working on designing a program using `selenium` and `python`, cable of clicking on a series of post (n=235), starting from the oldest one (#235) moving all the way up to the newest (#1). So far, I have a version of it that partially does what is supposed to be doing. I say partially because some of the tasks that I want to incorporate into this program are not there yet (and I having troubles writing the code).
So, what I have so far is a program that scrolls all the way to the end of the webpage, locates the oldest post and clicks on it.

Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

     

#for i in range(1000):
lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
match=False
while(match==False):
    lastCount = lenOfPage
    time.sleep(3)
    lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    if lastCount==lenOfPage:
        match=True
time.sleep(5)
totalLink=235#len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//div[1]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[3]//a[1]//i[1]"))
for i in range (1,totalLink-1):
    linkxPath = "//div["+str(235-i+1)+"]//div[1]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[3]//a[1]//i[1]"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,linkxPath))).click()
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_xpath(linkxPath))
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath(linkxPath).click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='share-title']").click()
    #driver.refresh()
```

The problems:

1. I have not been able to incorporate the scroll up feature. Right now, what I am doing is refreshing the page and scrolling all the way back to end of the page, locate the oldest post and clicking on it. The webpage that I am working on, has this feature that once I click on an older post, this post becomes a new post (e.g., if I click on post #235, after refreshing the page it becomes post #1).
2. I have not been able to figure a way to automize the click feature, right now I have 3 lines in my code that locate the items and the click on it (not really efficient because I need to update 235 post and I am doing it 3 at a time). By looking at the items xpath I have noted that only one number changes, but I am unsure if it can be modified.

Elements xpath:

```
//div[235]//div[1]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[3]//a[1]//i[1]
//div[234]//div[1]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[3]//a[1]//i[1]
.
.
.
//div[1]//div[1]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[3]//a[1]//i[1]
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Posh_Auto.py", line 39, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,linkxPath))).click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <i class="icon share-gray"></i> is not clickable at point (860, 8). Other element would receive the click: <div aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

Please let me know your thoughts and comments.

Thank you

Comment: "//div["+ i+"]//div[1]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[3]//a[1]//i[1]" would work in a for loop.

Comment: What website are you using selenium on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.get("https://poshmark.com/closet/alyssascott688?sort_by=added_desc&just_in_closet=true")

# Waiting for Page to load successfully
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@title='poshmark-logo']")))

# Since page is loading new elements after each scroll to bottom
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(2)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
shareLinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//i[@class='icon share-gray']")

#Total such share link
print(len(shareLinks))

for i in range(1, len(shareLinks)+1):
    xpathLink = "(//i[@class='icon share-gray'])["+str(226-i+1)+"]"
    #Creating Fresh elements so won't get stale element exception
    clickLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathLink)
    #Scroll to element and click
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickLink)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickLink)
    #After clicking on Share Link, I am copying the link. You can perform any other action if you want
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon copy-white']"))).click()
    # To insure which link its clicking, I am printing link number
    print("copied : " + str(226-i+1))
    # Waiting for links to be clickable before go to next
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpathLink)))
```

Comment: I think you should get the size first and loop that many times and use the index of size to click on the //div[235]/div[1]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[3]//a[1]//i[1] everytime and refresh. LinkxPath should just be the last one at all times.

Comment: @Perro I did not get your question ? Are you saying it clicked for first time but not able to click second time onward? Also as you mentioned after each refresh as div[235] is becoming div[1] so what is happening to subsequent divs? Ideally in such case you last div will again become div[235]. In such scenarios As suggested by Arundeep linkXpath should be always path to div[235]. Please let me know if after refresh you want to click always last link ?

Comment: @rahulrai sorry my question was not clear. I have updated my code in the post. The problem with it, is that it only performs the clicking action once, then I get an error. You are right, my idea is to look for the element (e.g., 235) click and then move to the next (e.g., 234) so that it eventually gets to the first element (that is at the top of the page). Once that is all done, refresh the page.

Comment: Try the updated code . It will click all div[235] , div[234]....div[1].

Comment: @rahulrai once again thank you for you comments and help. Based on your suggestion I have changed my code. As a result, my program is now scrolling to the end of the page and clicking on elements div[235], div[234] and div[233], unfortunately when it is time to scroll up to look for the next element div[232] , I get the and error (please refer to the original post). Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Perro - Amigo first of all thanks for  asking such a wonderful question. I have updated the solution and given comments wherever its possible to make you understand. Also I am modifying question title to make it more generic. for demonstartion purpose I have taken user alyssascott688, but it will work for any such page.

Comment: @rahulrai the solution works perfect. Thank you so much for your help and input.